# A chain of inequalities with words - aligned

Tags: align, brackets

How would one write this in TeX? I tried basic align techniques, but one also needs to align the words inside the brackets on the right-hand side and for me it does strange things.[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Pardon the transcription inaccuracies...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine,mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
\[
\setstackgap{L}{.9\normalbaselineskip}
\begin{aligned}
2^d &\mathrel{\mathop{\le}\limits^{(1)}} \max\{...\}\\
 &\mathrel{\mathop{\le}\limits^{(2)}} \max\Biggl\{
\#S\Bigg|\Centerstack[l]{$S \subset \mathcal{R}^d$ such that...\\
there is a strip $\mathscr{S}(i,j)$ that\\
lying in the parallel boundary...}
\Biggr\}\\
 &\mathrel{\mathop{\le}\limits^{(3)}} \max\Biggl\{
\#S\Bigg|\Centerstack[l]{$S \subset \mathcal{R}^d$ such that...\\
the convex hull $P:= \mathrm{conv}(S)$...\\
point, but they only touch...}
\Biggr\}
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use a `\parbox`, which I complete with a suitable definition for set descriptions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\providecommand{\given}{}
\newcommand{\setseparator}{% used only in \Set
  \mathrel{}
  \mathclose{}
  \delimsize|
  \mathopen{}
  \mathrel{}
}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\Set}[1]{\lbrace}{\rbrace}{%
  \renewcommand{\given}{\setseparator}%
  #1%
}

\newcommand{\longsetdescription}[2][.6\displaywidth]{\parbox{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
2^d
& \le \max\Set{\#S\given a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j} \\
& \le \max\Set*{\#S\given\longsetdescription{
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
      }}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The command `\longsetdescription` accepts an optional argument for the size, default is 60% of the width assigned for the current display.

[image]

Comment: is the mathrel+mathclose and mathopen+mathclose better than the more manual example I use in the mathtools manual?

Comment: @daleif In my opinion, yes, but you probably have more test cases.

Comment: Not really. BTW: your version allows line breaks on both sides of the `|`, is that desirable? My test version should only allow breaks after.